# VBA Find What Default Text

Tags: excel, vba

How do you prevent Visual Basic from setting the default find (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) text to whatever iss selected?

For clarity: In Visual Basic for Applications if you bring up a Find box it automaticaly sets the "Find What:" text to whatever you have selected in the code window. Idealy, if I closed the find box it would reopen with the find text I had last used (like every other program).

Visual Basic for Applications 7.1
Microsoft Excel 365

[image]

I've checked all the standard menus, there's not many and I'm not sure where else an option like that could be stored.

While this is technically in the Visual Basic for Applications on an Excel file I've also observed the behavior in the other office applications.

Comment: I doubt this is possible.

Comment: Don't select anything before a ctrl f? Why would you select something then go ctrl+f if that's not what you wanted to look for? I think it's just a matter of perspective: in other IDE I find annoying that I have to retype what I have in selection in order to find it

Comment: I would guess to save the last searched string and call it in a custom find userform.  If you want to get really sloppy, you could send keys `ctrl+f` and input the last saved string into the box...

Comment: The dropdown box should list previous searches in that session. You can't alter the default behaviour as far as I know.

Comment: The VBA Find is designed to work in 2 ways. **1.** Show you text where the cursor is or show the selected text. **2.** If the cursor is on a blank area then again there are 2 possibilities. **a.** Show the text from the previous search. **b.** If there is no text from previous search, then show nothing. **Having said that** Is it possible to clear the text from the VBA Find window? **Answer:**  YES. **How?** Using APIs. At a click of a button, VBA Find is launched and the text is cleared (if there is any)

Comment: Perhaps could be accomplished with AutoHotKey as well (IfWinActive, and then run a Ctrl+f, ctrl+a, del in sequence).

Comment: You say 'close and re-open' the Find dialog so I guess your problem is that you've performed one Find and want to perform the same Find again instead of a Find with the selected text ... how about using F3 (or Shift+F3 to 'find up')? If you want to keep the 'text to find' but have moved your cursor away then press F3 (so the cursor is again on the text you actually want to find) followed by Ctrl+F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclusions, you can't.

After looking further and feed back from others it appears you can't change the behavior of the Find What input box within Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications. However, if you're looking to repeat a search pressing F3 to Find Next while your cursor is in the code window accomplishes much of the same thing.

Thanks JohnM, I think this is as close to an answer as I'm likly to get.